# Django static files are broken

Tags: django

I'm trying to add a background picture to the hero section in Django, But whenever I open that URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/bg.png` it says `'img\bg.png' could not be found` I also attempted to open other urls, but they are broken.

```
#settings

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = 'E:\coding\django\pawnhost\static'

#urls


from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("core.urls")),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

#html


<section class="Hero">
    ...
</section>

#CSS (base.html)


{% load static %}

<style>

.Hero {
        background-image: url({% static 'img/bg.png' %});
}
</style>
```

Comment: Use double backslashes or `r'...'` here: `STATIC_ROOT = 'E:\coding\django\pawnhost\static'`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852939/entering-directories-as-strings-in-python

Comment: @Selcuk It still won't work I've already tried to add r to the static root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url:

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_DIR)
```

settings:

```
STATIC_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'static'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR/"static_root"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

try to use STATIC_DIR & STATIC_ROOT different name for confusion.